# Can a review decision be reversed?

Tags: support

I have mistakenly rejected an edit in my review of "Suggested Edits". Is there some way of reversing what I've done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Such a feature won't be implemented either: [The ability to undo reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186590/295232)

It's one of the reasons most review queue items require reviews from *multiple* users; mistakes like this happen from time to time, but you can certainly hope the other reviewers will approve the edit.